# Why are the bounds of my CGRect awkward?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a timer for chess, and I'd like there to be a *blur* whenever one of the sides is not playing, but for some reason, the following code puts the blur effect in the wrong place, unless the app is opened from landscape mode:

```
var blackSeconds: Int = 0
var whiteSeconds: Int = 0

var blackTimer: Timer = Timer()
var whiteTimer: Timer = Timer()

let blurEffectViewForBlack = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
let blurEffectViewForWhite = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    blackLabel.text = formatTime(time: blackSeconds)
    whiteLabel.text = formatTime(time: whiteSeconds)
    inputOutlet.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
        string: "Enter number of seconds",
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]
    )

    let width: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width
    let height: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.height

    print(width, height)

    blurEffectViewForBlack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width / 2, height: height)
    blurEffectViewForBlack.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    blurEffectViewForBlack.alpha = 0.9
    blurEffectViewForBlack.isHidden = true

    blurEffectViewForWhite.frame = CGRect(x: width / 2, y: 0, width: width / 2, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    blurEffectViewForWhite.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    blurEffectViewForWhite.alpha = 0.9
    blurEffectViewForWhite.isHidden = true

    view.addSubview(blurEffectViewForBlack)
    view.addSubview(blurEffectViewForWhite)
}
```

I fear this has something to do with the fact that `self.view.frame.size` doesn't change according to orientation. Note that I've also tried `self.view.bounds` and it produced the same result. see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EZEd.png).

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to do anything related to layout. That should be done in (for example) [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks a lot! That fixed it.